# Prunning PostgreSQL Windows Install Package

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm planning on distributing postgresql with my windows application but the size of postgresql is too big, what are some of the file that can be removed from the package to reduce the size of the postgresql server?

Comment: What Postgres features are you relying on? Do you require DB features that SQLite cannot provide?

Comment: The application uses multiple threads and user can import large data while simultaneously using other modules my software offer import large data while simultaneously using other modules my software offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can safely remove the following directories:

- include
- doc
- installer
- pgAdmin III
- scripts
- StackBuilder
- symbols (not 100% sure about this, but I think they are only needed for debugging)

(Based on the layout after a typical install)

You can also delete

- bin\stackbuilder.exe
- bin\pgAdmin3.exe